# How to reload JSF ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, ejb, resourcebundle

I am currently designing an application that needs to be available in so many different languages and after much research I reverted in to using resouceBundles. I am using java se 1.6 and java ee 6 with jsf 1.2 and glassfish 3.1..

I got following codes from all over the internet and arranged it in a manner to make sense.. Now the question is, the ResourceBundle loads alright, however it doesnt get refreshed.. i tried so many different ResourceBundle.clearCache() methods but none of those seems to be working...

Please note in the Control class I am checking the locale and loading the data to fit that. This will be later replaced by a database backed system. This is only test code to make sure i have the underlying structure working...

CODE_SAMPLE: LocalTest.java - The Resource Bundle

```
public class LocalTester extends ResourceBundle {

    protected static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "local.lantest.LocalTester";
    protected static final Control UTF8_CONTROL = new LocalTesterControl();

    public LocalTester() {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(), UTF8_CONTROL));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        return parent.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    public static Control getUTF8_CONTROL() {
        return UTF8_CONTROL;
    }
}
```

CODE_SAMPLE: LocalTestControl.java - The Resource Bundle Control

```
public class LocalTesterControl extends Control {

    @Override
    public boolean needsReload(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, ResourceBundle bundle, long loadTime) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimeToLive(String baseName, Locale locale) {
        return TTL_DONT_CACHE;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException {

        System.out.println("---------------------------LOADING LOCALE PACK-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Printing baseName = " + baseName);
        System.out.println("Printing locale.getLanguage() = " + locale.getLanguage());
        System.out.println("Printing locale.getDisplayLanguage() = " + locale.getDisplayLanguage());

        ResourceBundle rbdl;

        if (locale.getLanguage().compareTo("fr") == 0) {
            System.out.println("------- LOAD FRENCH language pack load");
            rbdl = new ListResourceBundle() {

                @Override
                protected Object[][] getContents() {
                    Object[][] aa = {
                        {"welcome", "FR- Welcome" + (new Date().toString())},
                        {"message", "FR- message"}, 
                        {"signoff", "FR- Sign Off"}, 
                        {"parametWelcome", "FR-Para Meter Welcome... {0} is parameter..."},
                        {"numberParaFormat", "FR-NUMBER parameter = {0}...."}
                    };
                    return aa;
                }
            };
        } else if (locale.getLanguage().compareTo("es") == 0) {
            System.out.println("------- LOAD ESPANIOLA language pack load");
            rbdl = new ListResourceBundle() {

                @Override
                protected Object[][] getContents() {
                    Object[][] aa = {
                        {"welcome", "ES- Welcome" + (new Date().toString())},
                        {"message", "ES- message"},
                        {"signoff", "ES- Sign Off"},
                        {"parametWelcome", "ES-Para Meter Welcome... {0} is parameter..."},
                        {"numberParaFormat", "ES-NUMBER parameter = {0}...."}
                    };
                    return aa;
                }
            };
        } else {
            System.out.println("------- LOAD DEFAULT language pack load");
            rbdl = new ListResourceBundle() {

                @Override
                protected Object[][] getContents() {
                    Object[][] aa = {
                        {"welcome", "EN- Welcome" + (new Date().toString())},
                        {"message", "EN- message"}, 
                        {"signoff", "EN- Sign Off"}, 
                        {"parametWelcome", "EN-Para Meter Welcome... {0} is parameter..."},
                        {"numberParaFormat", "EN-NUMBER parameter = {0}...."},
                        {"notrans", "EN- No Language Translation"}
                    };
                    return aa;
                }
            };
        }

        return rbdl;
    }
}
```

And finally the Faces config:

```
<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>local.lantest.LocalTester</base-name>
            <var>bundi</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Any help and advise is much valued.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload resource bundle in web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325164/how-to-reload-resource-bundle-in-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

1. First, create several ApplicationResources using locale codes:

   - ApplicationResources.properties (default file)
   - ApplicationResources_es.properties (spanish file, i.e.)
2. Modify faces-config.xml to support different locales:

```xml
  <application>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>en</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
  <message-bundle>com.business.resources.ApplicationResources</message-bundle>
 </application>
```

Edit your jsf and add:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.business.resources.ApplicationResources" var="msg"/>
```

You can see a locale list in the following website: http://www.science.co.il/language/locale-codes.asp