# Changes in property files does not reflect in page while using Glassfish 3.1.2 server

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, glassfish-3

I am using NetBeans IDE but I am using Glassfish externally(means not that which comes with NetBeans. I am using GlassFish through terminal in ubantu). In my project I am using several property file to load label on page. But the problem is when modification made to property file at run time, that changes are not reflected on page. I need to restart Glassfish server. ResourceBundle entry are made in faces-config file.

```
//faces-config.xml
<locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
</locale-config>
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>ValidationMessages</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
<message-bundle>ValidationMessages</message-bundle>
```

I know, I need to clear cache of ResourceBundle( using ResourceBundle.clearCache(); ) when changes are made in property file. And I already tried that. This solution perfectly works in jetty. But it is ineffective when I use glassfish server.

Comment: please let me know if you need more detail....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed this [Glassfish Bug Report](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15657).  In short, `clearCache()` is not effective, and there doesn't appear to be a workaround at this time.

I also came across this SO question - [How to reload resource bundle in web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325164/how-to-reload-resource-bundle-in-web-application) - but I couldn't figure out if the main Answer would be applicable in your case; i.e. if it works on Glassfish.

Comment: That bug is reported more than  a year ago and Glassfish people does't have solution for that at this time. STRANGE....

Comment: It is marked as unimportant ... so it is not strange at all that they haven't worked on it.  But, hey, you are free to develop a fix for the problem and submit it as a patch or pull request or whatever.